# Prim's Algorithm doesn't make proper spanning tree

Tags: python

```py
def prim(graph):
    que = queue.PriorityQueue()
    mst = []
    visited = set()

    # Generate edge information with tuple and push it to Priority Queue
    for outer_key in graph.keys():
        for inner_key, inner_cost in graph[outer_key].items():
            que.put((inner_cost, outer_key, inner_key))

    while que.empty() is False:
        edge = que.get()
        cost, frm, to = edge

        if to in visited:
            continue

        visited.add(frm)
        visited.add(to)
        mst.append(edge)

        for next_to, cost in graph[to].items():
            if next_to not in visited:
                que.put((cost, to, next_to))

    return mst
```

[Full source code](http://jdoodle.com/a/1rET)

I'm making very simple Prim's Algorithm with Python. In this code, graph is made with nested dictionary. I pushed all edges(tuple) to Priority Queue, get them one by one from it, check whether is it a visited vertex, and pushed adjacent vertex to Priority Queue.

However, the shape of final spanning tree is like this:

```
                   2
  [A]        [B]-------[C]
   |
 5 |
   |
  [D]--------[E]       [F]
         6              |
                    +---+
                    | 3
             [G]----+
```

I want to know where the problem is and how to fix it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prim's algorithm starts from an arbitrary vertex. It then adds all its edges to the priority queue and starts the loop.

You added **all** the edges to the queue (maybe you got confused with Kruskal which does something else).

A working code is hence:

```
def prim(graph):
    que = queue.PriorityQueue()
    mst = []
    visited = set()

    # Generate edge information with tuple and push it to Priority Queue
    #for outer_key in graph.keys():
    #    for inner_key, inner_cost in graph[outer_key].items():
    #        que.put((inner_cost, outer_key, inner_key))

    starting_vertex = list(graph.keys())[0]

    for next_to, cost in graph[starting_vertex].items():
        if next_to not in visited:
            que.put((cost, starting_vertex, next_to))

    while que.empty() is False:
        edge = que.get()
        cost, frm, to = edge

        if to in visited:
            continue

        visited.add(frm)
        visited.add(to)
        mst.append(edge)

        for next_to, cost in graph[to].items():
            if next_to not in visited:
                que.put((cost, to, next_to))

    return mst
```